# Solving in Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve system of equations and inequalities in Mathematica. I am having the doubt that how much of preliminary processing should I do before solving. For example, consider a system of 100 eqns where the first and second 50 eqns can be solved independently. Then is it best to solve these separately, or pass everything to solve command and it has these kind of logics in itself.

Basically I want to know if I have to find independent equations or doing it is going to be redundant ?

```
timing[func_, tag_] := 
 Print[{NumberForm[First[AbsoluteTiming[func]], 10], tag}]
SetAttributes[timing, HoldAll];

eqn1list := {a == b^c, c > 0, c < 2, b > 0, b < 100}
var1list := {a, b, c}
eqn2list := {x == y*z, z > 0, z < 10, y > -10, b < 1}
var2list := {x, y, z}

timing[Solve[eqn1list, var1list]; 
 Solve[eqn2list, var2list], "separate"]

(*{0.7523705909,separate}*)

timing[Solve[Join[eqn1list, eqn2list], 
  Join[var1list, var2list]], "combined"]

(*{0.03423153424,combined}*)
```

When I tried the above code, one can see that combined is faster. But you cant say this is the case always. So if there is some Mathematica expert who knows lot how working of Mathematica solving and can give me advice as to how to proceed. Or atleast direct me towards some articles like [this](https://www.google.co.jp/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAAahUKEwjgxpj2zNfIAhUjrKYKHR32DPI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cecm.sfu.ca%2F~mmonagan%2Fpapers%2FCS-89-13.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEJ_HLKEkGsW6nPL_vhIAoKVZqArA&bvm=bv.105841590,d.dGY&cad=rja)

Comment: It depends; still, this seems like something you can answer yourself through some experimentation.

Comment: Is there any article or help page which explains the mathematical concepts considered while solving ?

Comment: Without going into too much detail, there's this article in the help center `tutorial/WhyYouDoNotUsuallyNeedToKnowAboutInternals` and also this `tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation`. In many cases, the approaches used by MMA might be considerably different in comparison to the approach one would use with pen and paper.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Thanks for the help. But there is no explicit info for these type questions or maybe I dont understand that level mathematics

Comment: @J.M. I know that it depends on the problem. But I am trying to figure a most efficient way to solve large systems. I dont know how exactly can I find the answer. Are you suggesting just to try for different systems as to how much time is taken (like brute force)?